# How to add a new column that flag duplicate of a column based on value of another column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I'm trying to modify a table by add a column that can flag down all the duplicate `Runner_Name` based on the `Track_Num`. I tried using:

```
SELECT [Track_Num],
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Track_Num] ORDER BY [Runner_Name]) - 1 As Dup,
       [Runner_Name]
  FROM [runner]
```

but it doesn't work, it's just sequencing the `Runner_Name`

The table `runner` that looks like this:

```
Track_Num     Runner_Name
   1            John
   1            John
   1            Jack
   2            Amy
   2            Mary
   2            John
   3            Josh
   3            Josh
   3            Taylor
```

The desired table that I hope to get is:

```
Track_Num     Runner_Name    Dup
   1            John          1
   1            John          1
   1            Jack          NULL
   2            Amy           NULL
   2            Mary          NULL
   2            John          NULL
   3            Josh          1
   3            Josh          1
   3            Taylor        NULL
```

Comment: what are the values in dup is it only 1 and null?

Comment: Nice job on the question - sample data and expected results as text, and a nice, simple, clear description of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have a fifth option to choose from?

```
SELECT *, dup=(select 1 from runner 
               where track_num=r.track_num and runner_name=r.runner_name 
               having count(*)>1)
FROM runner r
```

This approach works without any windowing functions or common table expressions,

See the demo here: https://rextester.com/WPLCLP17296

Here is a demo with **null** values - they are **not flagged** as duplicates: https://rextester.com/AND4821

Comment: what if I have ```NULL``` in the ```Runner_Name```? the code will identify all the ```NULL``` with the same ```Track_Num``` as duplicate as well, right?

Comment: `NULL` cannot be compared to any other value, not even itself, Therefore a `null` value in the runner_name will never pop up as a duplicate with my version. If you *want* the `null` values to appear as duplicates we would have to use some `coalesce()`function to turn them into "real" values ...

Comment: nice, I'll try that out. Thank you

Comment: Will this work with  DB2 Database? Thanks for any info.

Comment: Apparently, it will also work in db2, see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/BVyTn33N - I had to slightly adapt the Syntax to `SELECT *, (select 1 from runner t where track_num=r.track_num and runner_name=r.runner_name having count(*)>1) as dup
FROM runner r;`.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann It seems that is working but it was taking more than 5 minutes loading so I had to cancel the script. Thank you so much anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just wrap the window function in `sign(nullif( ... ,1))`

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,Dup = sign(NullIf(sum(1) over (partition by  [Track_Num],[Runner_Name] ) ,1))
 From [runner]
```

Returns

```
Track_Num   Runner_Name Dup
1   Jack    NULL
1   John    1
1   John    1
2   Amy     NULL
2   John    NULL
2   Mary    NULL
3   Josh    1
3   Josh    1
3   Taylor  NULL
```

Comment: John, can I do ```ALTER TABLE [runner] ADD Dup AS sign(NullIf(sum(1) over (partition by  [Track_Num],[Runner_Name] ) ,1))``` ? @John Cappelletti

Comment: @cheklapkok Nope.  a window function can only exist in a select.   Perhaps a view  or even a table-valued function instead

Comment: got it. I'll create another table then. One last question, what if I have NULL in the ```Runner_Name```, it will create ```1``` because it'll treat all the NULL for the same ```Track_Num``` as the same. Thank you sir.

Comment: @cheklapkok One null per track would not be flagged as a dupe.  Multiple null runner names would be a dupe   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0af7aac524fdf95aa8836721989f9109

Comment: Is there anyway I can avoid those duplicate ```NULL``` then?

Comment: @cheklapkok Sure take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=18175c0ff48284476dfa7be7d5e1bd00   Notice the   IsNull([Runner_Name],newid())

Answer (score 0):

If I undrestand your question correctly, then try this

```
select [Track_Num],
       [Runner_Name],
       Case when Count(1) > 1 then 1 else null end as Dup
from runner
group by [Track_num], [Runner_Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Common Table Expression` to identify the runners that have duplicates:

```
With cte_dups
As
(
    Select 
        r.Track_Num
        , r.Runner_Name
        , Count(*) As Track_Runner_Count
    From dbo.Runner As r
    Group By 
        r.Track_Num
        , r.Runner_Name
)
Select 
    r.Track_Num
    , r.Runner_Name
    , Iif(c.Track_Runner_Count > 1, 1, Null)
From dbo.Runner As r
    Left Outer Join cte_dups As c
        On c.Track_Num = r.Track_Num
        And c.Runner_Name = r.Runner_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

First `group by Track_Num, Runner_Name` to get the count of each combination and then join to the table:

```
select 
  r.Track_Num, 
  r.Runner_Name,
  case 
    when g.counter > 1 then 1
    else null
  end Dup 
from runner r inner join ( 
  select Track_Num, Runner_Name, Count(*) counter
  from runner
  group by Track_Num, Runner_Name
) g on g.Track_Num = r.Track_Num and g.Runner_Name = r.Runner_Name
```